# Accessing Components in JFrame from External Class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am having trouble accessing several components in a JFrame to use their setText("...") method. My main is in a seperate class, because the actual program has many windows that need to be managed at the same time.

```
public GameWindow() {

    initialize();
    gameFrame.setVisible(true);
}

private void initialize() {     
    gameFrame = new JFrame();

JTextPane gameTextPane = new JTextPane();       // text pane to contain all game text
    gameTextPanel.add(gameTextPane);
```

And this is my main:

```
public class GameMain {
    public static GameWindow gW = new GameWindow();
    //I have tried using the code below with various numbers, but the "setText()" method is never available
    gW.getGameFrame().getContentPane().getComponent(x);
}
```

I am trying to set the text of this from a **seperate class**, but I can not access the components.
Ultimately, the final code should look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // make the GUI and initilize
    changeTheText();
}

public static void changeTheText() {
    [CODE TO ACCESS TEXTFIELD].setText("Hello World");
}
```

I have tried many different methods I've found searching around, but I don't really understand any of them, and none of them still allow me to access the methods I need.

Comment: by default there are getsetters or a few variations about constructor, for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame

Comment: *"the actual program has many windows"*  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the declaration of the `JTextPane` out of the `initialize` method to make it a parameter so you can acces it anytime from within the class. To make it accessible from another class you can either make it public or add a set method. Like this:

```
public class GameWindow {
    private JTextPane gameTextPane;
    ...
    private void initialize(){...}
    ...
    public void setText(String s) {
        gameTextPane.setText(s);
    }
}
```

To change your text from the main class:

```
gW.setText("This is a cool text");
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `setText(String text)` method in your `GameWindow` class. In that method call `setText` on the components you need to change.

Comment: How would I call that? gameTextPane.setText(text); returns an error that it can't be found, and similar variations give similar errors.

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace? It's difficult to tell what's going on without it

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: gameTextPane cannot be resolved

 at GameWindow.setGameText(GameWindow.java:376)
 at GameMain.main(GameMain.java:44)'